# Strange C++ new operator usage

Tags: c++, new-operator

While digging in a C++ project, I encountered a strange usage of C++'s `new` operator:

```
int arr[5];
ClassA* a = new(arr) ClassA();
```

Would you please help me understand this syntax?

Comment: google "placement new" or see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new

Comment: @Askyane I have included a brief summary and a link for your perusal

Answer (score 2):

It's the placement new syntax - it allows you to construct an object at the pointed-to location in memory. Consider a "normal" use of new:

```
X *p = new X;
...
delete p;
```

You can achieve the same effect by doing:

```
#include <new>

...

void *buffer = ::operator new(sizeof(X));
X *p = new (buffer) X;
...
p->~X();
::operator delete(buffer);
```

The latter allocates enough memory to hold an `X` (without constructing an `X` in it), then explicitly constructs an `X` in the allocated memory. Later, it explicitly destructs the `X` it created and then deallocates the memory that contained it.

See also the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html

Answer (score 2):

The `new()` operator can take a `size` (size in bytes) `nothrow_value` (returns a null pointer instead of an `bad_alloc` exception) or `pointer`(construct the object in the already allocated memory pointed at by this pointer) argument, and in the usage you describe it is creating a new object at the memory location pointed to by `arr`.  For a decent guide on it I would look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new%5B%5D/).

In the case you cited it is using the pointer for arr to create its new instance of ClassA in.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is called the `placement new` syntax. It is typically used to construct an object on a pre-allocated buffer. This is useful when building a memory pool, a garbage collector or simply when performance and exception safety are paramount (there's no danger of allocation failure since the memory has already been allocated, and constructing an object on a pre-allocated buffer takes less time).

```
char *buf  = new char[sizeof(string)]; // pre-allocated buffer
string *s1 = new (buf) string("test1");    // placement new
string *s2 = new string("test2");   //ordinary new
```

When it comes to deallocation, there is no `placement delete` that automatically does the magic. You should not deallocate every object that is using the memory buffer. Instead you should destruct each object manually, then delete[] only the original buffer

Comment: I think you meant destruct each object manually and then delete the original buffer, not the other way round.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz sorry for that stupid mistake. corrected it